# Why does the test coverage decrease when I provide services in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

Say, i have a very simple test in a brand new Angular project:

```js
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() =>
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    })
  );

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    expect(fixture.componentInstance).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

It has 100% code coverage when running `ng t --code-coverage --include "src/app/app.component.spec.ts"`. Simply providing a service:

```js
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [TempService],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    })
```

Reduces the code coverage, because the service has this method:

```
thing() {
  return false ? 1 : 2
}
```

Aren't unit tests supposed to be isolated and ignore files that are not related to what i'm testing?

Answer (score 0):

The coverage is most likely the whole project.

If there is a `temp.service.spec.ts`, it will see that `thing() { ... }` is never traversed from `app.component.spec.ts` or `temp.service.spec.ts` (or from any unit test).

Try deleting `temp.service.spec.ts` and you should be back to where you were before.

Also, you shouldn't be focused too much on coverage. I rather have 50% coverage with really good quality tests than 100% coverage with not so great tests.